# Combine Thumbnails to One Large Image with RMagick

Tags: ruby, thumbnails, rmagick

What's the shortest way to combine say 20 256x256 thumbnails into a single large image of 4 rows by 5 columns using RMagick?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming all the images are in the current directory and named from 1.jpg to n.jpg and row * col = n.

```
include Magick
row = NUM_ROWS
col = NUM_COLS
ilg = ImageList.new
1.upto(col) {|x| il = ImageList.new
1.upto(row) {|y| il.push(Image.read((y + (x-1)*col).to_s + ".jpg").first)}
ilg.push(il.append(false))}
ilg.append(true).write("out.jpg")
```