# How to combine images in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, shell, image-processing

I have 4 square images, 1,2,3 and 4 each with 2048x2048px.

I need to combine those into a 4096x4096px image, like this:

```
 1 2
 3 4
```

Right now I am doing this manually with Gimp, but the amount processing is growing and I would like to implement an automated solution.

Is there an easy way to do this in Ruby? (Rails gem would be ok or any shell command that can be run from inside a Rails app)

Comment: i would look into rmagick, it's a very powerful image processor

Comment: By combine images, did you mean that make 1 image from 4 images? Try rmagick.

Comment: Try composite! https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#composite_bang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try: **['rmagick' gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick/versions/2.15.2)**

```
require 'rmagick'

image_list = Magick::ImageList.new("image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png")
image_list.write("combine.png")
```

You can also refer this **[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736944/combine-thumbnails-to-one-large-image-with-rmagick)** it's similar to yours.

Comment: btw, the rmagick gem will also require you to install ImageMagick, which does the actual work (rmagick just provides a friendly ruby interface for ImageMagick).  Installing ImageMagick traditionally used to be a pain in the ass (whenever i did it anyway), but nowadays i think it's much easier to install.

Comment: @MaxWilliams : Yes I am agree with you. `ImageMagick` should be installed

Comment: I tried that, but I get an image of 2048x2048 with 4 images each on top the the other. I do not want them on top, I need first on top 0,0, second one on top 0, 2048, third one on top 2048, 0 and last one on top 2048, 2048.  Basically, I want to form a square image from 4 smaller square images, each of the 4 being a quarter of the new one

Answer (score 6):

I marked the accepted answer because was the starting point for solving my problem. I will also post the complete working solution here:

```
require 'rmagick'
class Combiner
include Magick

  def self.combine
    #this will be the final image
    big_image = ImageList.new

    #this is an image containing first row of images
    first_row = ImageList.new
    #this is an image containing second row of images
    second_row = ImageList.new

    #adding images to the first row (Image.read returns an Array, this is why .first is needed)
    first_row.push(Image.read("1.png").first)
    first_row.push(Image.read("2.png").first)

    #adding first row to big image and specify that we want images in first row to be appended in a single image on the same row - argument false on append does that
    big_image.push (first_row.append(false))

    #same thing for second row
    second_row.push(Image.read("3.png").first)
    second_row.push(Image.read("4.jpg").first)
    big_image.push(second_row.append(false))

    #now we are saving the final image that is composed from 2 images by sepcify append with argument true meaning that each image will be on a separate row
    big_image.append(true).write("big_image.jpg")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone landing here from Google and might be using a newer version of `MiniMagick (4.8.0)` & `Rails (5.2.0)`, I was able to combine images horizontally using this code:

```
# Replace this with the path to the images you want to combine
images = [
  "image1.jpg",
  "image2.jpg"
]

processed_image = MiniMagick::Tool::Montage.new do |image|
  image.geometry "x700+0+0"
  image.tile "#{images.size}x1"
  images.each {|i| image << i}
  image << "output.jpg"
end
```

Check out the [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) for `#geometry` options to handle resizing and placement. The current example will resize images to a `700px` height while maintaining the image's aspect ratio. `+0+0` will place the image with no gaps between them.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code under the hood, but this might save more memory than doing a `File.open` inside a `&block`

Comment: Use the `tile` option to achieve the question's desired layout. `image.tile "2x2"`

Comment: To get proccessed_image into a blob you needs to add image.stdout at end

Answer (score 1):

You might also try the [montage](https://rmagick.github.io/ilist.html#montage) method.