# Combining four images to one image for download

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site using Ruby on Rails that takes random images from a comic strip and returns 4 individual panels. I'd like to take those 4 images and make it into one downloadable image. Any guidance on how to do this or where to look would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like something that could be solved with a google search. If you have already done that and still come up empty, provide some details of the solutions you have tried and why you think they didn't work.

Comment: Do you need all 4 images merged into a single image or have them downloaded together inside a zip package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commentor pointed out, you're looking for RMagick:

https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick

Using the answer from [How to combine images in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751175/how-to-combine-images-in-ruby), and assuming you want a square layout for your new combined image, then try:

```
require 'rmagick'

image_list = Magick::ImageList.new("image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png")
image_list.write("combine.png")
```

This will take the 4 images and combine them into one, created in the same directory as the originals, called `combine.png`

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I had tried a few other solutions but this is the one that is going to be what I need.